# Pyspark - Replace value with Null Conditional

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, outliers

I need to replace my outliers with nulls in pyspark

```
df = df.withColumn("rpm", when(df["rpm"] >= 750, None).otherwise(df["rpm"]))
```

However I get this error:

```
TypeError: condition should be a Column
```

Comment: looks like you are closing the `withColumn` before calling `otherwise`:  `df = df.withColumn("rpm", when(df["rpm"] >= 750, None).otherwise(df["rpm"]))` ?

Comment: @anky, closing the `withColumn` after calling `otherwise` did not change the output - it returned the same error. Thanks

Comment: Okay,works for me, may be version of spark unless I am missing something: try : `df.withColumn("rpm", when(col("rpm") >= 750, None).otherwise(col("rpm")))` , import `col` if you have not already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anky's comment above works. Thanks.

```
df.withColumn("rpm", when(col("rpm") >= 750, None).otherwise(col("rpm")))
```